# Access "current_task" pointer of another cpu in a SMP based linux system

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, driver, smp

I'm writing some kernel driver where I need to check which thread is running at a certain point on another cores. My driver runs one kernel thread on per core and I need to sync from time to time some of the threads to do certain task. What I can observe from debugging logs is that sometimes one thread waits for some other threads too much. I did some patch where I store the `__preempt_count` on other cores to check if any softirq/hardirq or preemption disabled delays my thread.
I also used the FTRACE to check the irqsoff and preemptirqsoff for the max duration of IRQs off and preemption disabled.

Till now I was able to spot kerneloops thread which is disabling interrupts up to 20msec, which I find too long.
Did a `systemctl disable kerneloops` and got rid of this issue.

Now I seem to deal with some preemption disabled windows. For future analysis of this driver I need a way to figure out which threads are being executed at a particular point in time on other cores. I'm trying to use FTRACE mainly with events for IRQ entry/exit, I also use `trace_printk` to push some debug log in the ftrace buffer to to have everything in one log, etc.

However, one thing that I would like to do is to access the `current_task` structure of other cores (the `current` ptr) and print the `comm` field which gives the name of the task (or pid value).
But I'm having hard times in getting this done.

For `__preempt_count` I had no issue:

```
int *p = per_cpu_ptr(&__preempt_count,cpu);
pr_info("Preempt count of cpu%u is 0x%08x\n",cpu,*p);
```

So far I had no issue with declaring or accessing per cpu variables, but for some reason, the `current_task` pointer triggers a page fault when trying to access it.

```
char buf[10];
struct task_struct *task = per_cpu_ptr(current_task,cpu);
snprintf(buf,8,"%s",task->comm);
pr_info("Task name: %s",buf);
```

Above code triggers always a page fault, NULL ptr bla bla.
I couldn't find the reason till now. I tried to print the pointer value for `task`, I got the same page fault.

Might be this because the address is not accessible by other cores? In kernel space should not be the case afaik. I also had no issue till now with per core variables and I played a lot with this.

Bottom line: what would be the right approach to access the `current_task` of other cores and print the comm/pid fields?

Many Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong.
The difference between `__preempt_count` and `current_task` is that first one is defined as an int variable, whereas the 2nd one as a pointer to structure. In other words 1st one is defined as a variable and the 2nd one as a pointer.

Now, looking deeper into per cpu variables, they are just variables allocated by the compiler in separate memory locations, like an array. When `per_cpu_ptr` for a variable Foo is called, then the macro computes something like `Foo[cpu]`, but that means the `per_cpu_ptr` needs the actual base address of the variable, meaning the `&` so that it can compute the relative address value starting from this.

When declaring: `foo = per_cpu_ptr(&__preempt_count,cpu)` , this address is already given = `&__preempt_count`

When declaring: `bar = per_cpu_ptr(current_task,cpu)`, this address is not given, as the `&` is missing here. The current_task is a pointer but not the base address of the current_task array.

In both above cases the argument to `per_cpu_ptr` is a pointer, but here my understanding was wrong, it was not clear to me what is actually the pointer of the variable I need to pass, now it's clear: I have to pass the base address of the variable(var or pointer doesn't matter) so that the macro can compute the relative address for that cpu.

Therefore the right approaches that work are:

`bar = per_cpu(current_task,cpu)` which translates into `*per_cpu_var(&current_task,cpu)`

*or* directly

`bar = *per_cpu_var(&current_task,cpu);`